# JPA recursive entity StackOverflowError

Tags: jpa

I have a User entity generated in Netbeans from an existing database table. The table has a column lastUpdatedByUser that is a User entity. Most of the tables in this database have a lastUpdatedByUser column and queries against those entities correctly return a user object as part of the result.

Ex. Retrieve FROM ProductionTable WHERE date = 'someDate' has a lastUpdatedByUser object that shows who last updated the table row and the rest of their user attributes.

If the productionTable data is edited in the web-app and submitted I need to update the lastUpdatedByUser column.

```
Users userUpdating = usersService.selectUserEntityByUserId(userId);
Users userEntity = usersFacade.findSingleWithNamedQuery("Users.findByUserId", parameters);
SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.userId = :userId
```

returns a User object that contains a lastUpdatedByUser that is a User object that contains a lastUpdatedByUser that is a User object that contains a lastUpdatedByUser object.... (I have no clue how many there are, and twenty rows of these adds up)

After I persist this

```
productionEntity.setLastUpdatedByUser(userUpdating);
```

I get Json StackOverflowError in the next request for the updated entity

```
gson.toJson(updatedProductionEntity)
```

The Users entity definition:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "lastUpdatedByUser")
private Collection<Users> usersCollection;
@JoinColumn(name = "LastUpdatedByUser", referencedColumnName = "UserId")
@ManyToOne
private Users lastUpdatedByUser;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "lastUpdatedByUser")
private Collection<Production> productionCollection;
```

How can edit that such that I continue to get a user object as part of other entities like Production, but only a single lastUpdatedByUser object for a User entity?

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is my issue:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "LastUpdatedByUser", referencedColumnName = "UserId")
```

as I found a FK in the Users table to its own UserId

Love refactoring

================================

Drop that FK from the Users table and regenerate the entity in Netbeans and I get

```
private Integer lastUpdatedByUser;
```

like it should be
instead of

```
private Users lastUpdatedByUser;
```

Now I get to edit all the entities that have valid FKs into the Users table and code and...

Thanks for listening.